# How can I detect when outgoing call has been accepted

Tags: android, telephony

I am not able to detect when outgoing call has been answered, I have registered BroadcastReceiver for PHONE_STATE broadcast, but onReceive() gets called only when number is dialed and when call has ended.

Edit: If it is not possible with current API (1.5 or 1.6) please enlighten me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if an outgoing call has been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250455/detect-if-an-outgoing-call-has-been-answered)

Comment: Probably the below link is what you want.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250455/detect-if-an-outgoing-call-has-been-answered

Answer (score 1):

Android does not have specific listener yet for making sure whether the call(outgoing call) is answered or not. The moment a number is dialled it goes to off_hook state (in case of outgoing call). This is one one of the gap which android telephony has to yet come up with

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you getting any specific answers, so I try with a general one that may help.  If you are referring to calls going out the PSTN (Public switched telephone network), you won't be able to detect when the far side answers.  The way the phone network is structured, you won't be able to get that information except in very special cases.  Usually what you see on the handset is the moment the call is being routed out of the cell network.

As for in network (same subscriber), it may be possible to get that information, but I'm not sure.  You may want to look into CDMA or the protocol used by your carrier to see if it is going to even be possible to get farside information.

Comment: I don't know much about phone networks, but I do know that Cyanogen Mod 7 has a feature that the device vibrates when the call is answered. Hence, Android must know that the event happened, but doesn't appear to have any API entry point to register a listener for it.

Comment: Jim Rush your answer is very much confusion, actually the Android device do it.. so, there is a way to perform the task.. I view the log file and find each and every state of the phone in the debug mode.. I am further investigating.. it....

Comment: The phone application has access to private APIs that are not available in the SDK, so it is at this time not possible to achieve this.

Comment: @kamal_tech_view did you find the solution for detecting the event when an outgoing call is picked up?