# Detect if an outgoing call has been answered

Tags: android, android-intent, telephony

Once `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` has been broadcasted, I need to capture the following event of the other party answer. Could you advice on how to achieve that please? I know it is possible as the Android dialer app changes the green Android icon to the person's photo exactly when they pick up.

UPDATED: I've had a look at the source of the app on Android handling the outgoing calls. I noticed the following method in `ContactsUtils`:

```
/**
 * Kick off an intent to initiate a call.
 */

 public static void initiateCall(Context context, CharSequence
 phoneNumber) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED,
             Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber.toString(), null));
     context.startActivity(intent); }
```

I guess my answer is in the activity listening for `Intent.ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED`. So to rephrase my question: Does anyone know which activity handles `Intent.ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED`?

Comment: did yo u find the solution to your problem ? i am also looking for the same solution. I want to know if the other end user has picked up the call or he has disconnected

Comment: Currently it's not possible to detect when exactly they have picked up; the Caller app uses an internal intent for that.

Comment: yeah this is what I too concluded today :-|, anyways thanks

Comment: if u dont mind please provide info ,how do u use internal intent to get the info about outgoing call received.

Comment: Look at these threads. They disrcribe how to detect when the user answers the phone.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929750/how-to-know-the-moment-when-the-called-person-picks-up-his-phone

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513644/how-can-i-detect-when-a-call-is-answered

Comment: It's funny that duplicate questions get answers but this one has none.

Comment: did you find any way to achieve it? maybe by polling or using reflection on CallManager : http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java/?v=source ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when phone is answered or rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684866/how-to-detect-when-phone-is-answered-or-rejected)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there's such API and also there's no API for sending DTMFs due to the same reason that you can't tell when the call is being connected.

Answer (score 3):

It does not necessarily needs to be possible to capture this as an outside app. The green android icon is a part of the application that controls the call, so it does not need a broadcast to change the icon.

Comment: Yes, however, I do need to capture this event!

Answer (score 1):

As far as android's telephony manager is concerned u cannot detect programmatically whether the call has been answered or not. This is to say that u do not have the option to know when the user picked the phone at other end.
Android has got 3 states of telephony manager and none of them are capable of detecting whether the call was actually answerd or not(IN CASE OF OUTGOING CALLS)

Comment: not true onCallStateChanged does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you may be able to do this is by **parsing the Logcat logs**, no PhoneStateListener event is available for that.

Some are asking for it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14266

Anyway, in versions above Android 4.2 as Logcat is "sandboxed" it may be impossible...

Comment: If we set targetSdkVersion of our app to < 4.2. Can we then read the system logs using logcat?

Comment: i'm afraid not. because it's the Phone app's logs that are sand boxed. It doesn't matter which sdk your app is using.

Comment: Not true there is a onCallStateChanged event that can be used