# How to know the moment when the called person picks up his phone

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect if an outgoing call has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250455/detect-if-an-outgoing-call-has-been-answered)

How can I know the moment when the person I call "picks up" his phone?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as Android's telephony manager is concerned you **cannot** detect programmatically whether your call has been answered or not.

But for incoming calls it is possible, using `PhoneStateListener`. When YOU 'pick up' the phone, the state changes to `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        try {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // do something...
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                // you picked up the phone
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                // do something...
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown phone state=" + state);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {}
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your rapid and accurate response.

Have a good day !

Comment: Wrong CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK will be set immediately when the number is dialed and NOT when the person picks up the phone.

Comment: Is there any way to detect this for OUTGOING calls?

Comment: as AndroidDev said, with an out going call the state will be changed to OFFHOOK immediately.

Comment: this doesn't work for outgoing calls. only for incoming calls. did you find any way to achieve it for outgoing calls? maybe by polling or using reflection on CallManager : http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java/?v=source ?

Comment: I edited it for clarity. It is possible only for incoming calls, as it has been mentioned.