# Pausing a service in background in android

Tags: android, service

I am working on an app in which I am playing media player using service. The app is working fine but when i receive a call or a message, the music keeps on playing. My requirement is when I get a call, the music should be paused and on call disconnection, it should resume from where it has stopped. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you coded your app but this should help you.
Check out this [How to know the moment when the called person picks up his phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929750/how-to-know-the-moment-when-the-called-person-picks-up-his-phone) You would just need to pause the music in the switch statement for the specified event

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        try {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // do something...
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                // this state is the one you're looking for
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                // do something...
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown phone state=" + state);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {}
    } 
};
```

EDIT: here is another link  [Detect if an outgoing call has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250455/detect-if-an-outgoing-call-has-been-answered)

Comment: It has nothing has to do with telephony manager. I am looking for a generic solution. I had given the example of incoming call to explain the situation.