# How can I detect when a call is answered?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect if an outgoing call has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250455/detect-if-an-outgoing-call-has-been-answered)

I'm writing an android application.

What I have right now is:
I'm able to detect an outgoing call (by `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`),
and right after, I getting the `OFFHOOK_STATE` (It's still ringing...)

My question is how can I detect when a call is answered?

Comment: hey did u find the answer this question