# What is the status of an outgoing call

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start a new activity once an outgoing call is activated (NEW_OUTGOING_CALL). However I dont know where I should start my new activity in the PhoneStateListener class that I created (method onCallStateChanged) Where do I start my intent?CALL_STATE_IDLE?CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK?

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: 
        Log.d("System out", "IDLE");
        NOTOFFHOOK = true;      
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  method called
        Log.d("System out", "OFFHOOK, it flag: " + NOTOFFHOOK);

        if (NOTOFFHOOK == false) {
            // do your work on receiving call.
        }
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:   
        Log.d("System out", "RINGING");
        // do your work while ringing.

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250455/detect-if-an-outgoing-call-has-been-answered

Comment: I think your above responce has to do with incoming call? I need to get the outgoing call...Thanks!

Comment: I haven't checked it but I would think that an outgoing call would also 'ring', albeit on the internal speaker.  It's still ringing though.  Does it not work to start your new activity under the CALL_STATE_RINGING case?

Comment: Ringing state never happens for an outgoing call in android. Only Offhook or Idle.