# Android how to find the outgoing call has been attended

Tags: android, android-service

I am currently working on a call recording app. I am able to get broadcast when the phone call is attended, if it is incoming call `(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)`. But for outgoing call the OFFHOOK is fired immediately after `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING`. 
So I couldn't find if the other person has attended the call or not and when he attended the call, to record it. 
Any help will be thankful.

Comment: There is no way you can do this.

Comment: But I have found some call recording apps in market..

Comment: Ohh I see. And yes, even the phone itself does it when the other party receives the call. But even I had googled for this for a loooong time, but found no luck. Anyways, if you find the solution please revert back, and if possible tag me in your comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if an outgoing call has been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250455/detect-if-an-outgoing-call-has-been-answered)